# How to extract both node names and their eigenvector centralities in a datatable

Tags: r, networking, igraph

I need to create a datatable with both node names and their eigenvector centralities but the problem is that I cannot extract the node names and I use:

```
#CENTRALITY
library(igraph)
library(magrittr)
library(visNetwork)
library(data.table)
library(geomnet)

#Load dataset
data(lesmis)

#Nodes
nodes <- as.data.frame(lesmis[2])
colnames(nodes) <- c("id", "label")

#id has to be the same like from and to columns in edges
nodes$id <- nodes$label

#Edges
edges <- as.data.frame(lesmis[1])
colnames(edges) <- c("from", "to", "width")


#Create graph for Louvain
graph <- graph_from_data_frame(edges, directed = FALSE)

graph <- simplify(graph)

library(DT)
ev<-evcent(graph)$vector
datatable(ev)
```

Comment: not sure which one but when you load the libraries library(visNetwork)
library(geomnet)
library(igraph)
library(dplyr) it works

Comment: oh sorry my fault

Comment: did that work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you already have almost everything done here. Unless I am misunderstanding, this finishes off your request.

```
## create a data.frame with required columns
nodes$ev = evcent(graph)$vector

## if you really want a data.table
nodes.dt = as.data.table(nodes)
```